# Extjs binding a form to a model that has associations

Tags: extjs, extjs-stores

I have the following JSON structure:

```
userAuth
----userAccount -- hasOne
----userAccountDetails -- hasMany
```

I want to show a form that shows data from userAuth and userAccount and then a grid with a row for each row in userAccountDetails

Here is the code for userAuth model:

```
Ext.define('xxxx.model.UserAuth', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
       { name: 'id' },
       { name: 'email' },
       { name: 'userName' },
       { name: 'refIdStr' },
       { name: 'displayName' },
       { name: 'modifiedDate', type: 'date', }
    ],

    requires: [
        'xxxx.model.UserAccount',
        'xxxx.model.UserAuthDetails',
    ],

    hasMany: [
        {
            model: 'xxxx.model.UserAuthDetails',
            name: 'authDetails',
            foreignKey: 'userAuthId',
            associationKey: 'userAuthDetails',

        }
    ],

    hasOne: [
        {
            model: 'xxxx.model.UserAccount',
            name: 'userAcount',
            associationKey: 'userAccount',
            getterName: 'getUserAccount',
            setterName: 'setUserAccount',
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        startParam: 'skip',
        limitParam: 'take',
        url: settings.ApiUrl + '/model/UserAuth/?format=json',
        baseParams: {
            skip: '0',
            take: '10',
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});
```

And userAccount model

```
Ext.define('xxxx.model.UserAccount', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
       { name: 'username' },
       { name: 'id' },
       { name: 'name' },
       { name: 'email' },
       { name: 'slug' },
       { name: 'facebookId' }
    ],

    belongsTo: 'xxxx.model.UserAuth',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        startParam: 'skip',
        limitParam: 'take',
        url: settings.ApiUrl + '/model/UserAccount/?format=json',
        baseParams: {
            skip: '0',
            take: '10',
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});
```

and userAuthDetails:

```
Ext.define('xxxx.model.UserAuthDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
       { name: 'id' },
       { name: 'userAuthId' },
       { name: 'provider' },
       { name: 'userId' },
       { name: 'userName' },
       { name: 'displayName' },
       { name: 'firstName' },
       { name: 'lastName' },
       { name: 'email' },
       { name: 'modifiedDate' },
       { name: 'provider' },
    ],

    belongsTo: [
        {
            model: 'xxxx.model.UserAuth',
            isntanceName: 'userAuth',
            getterName: 'getUserAuthDetails',
            setterName: 'setUserAuthDetails',
            associationKey: 'userAuthDetails'
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        startParam: 'skip',
        limitParam: 'take',
        url: settings.ApiUrl + '/model/UserAuthDetails/?format=json',
        baseParams: {
            skip: '0',
            take: '10',
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});
```

Loading the store works and the associations work - when i call `record.getUserAccount().get('email')` it returns what I'd expect - so all that is working.

Now, my question is - how the hell do i get that data into the form described above?

I have tried doing things like:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'username',
    allowBlank: false,
    maxLength: 100,
    name: 'userAccount.userName'
}
```

thinking the association name might be a good hint for it - but that doesn't work...

Data from the top most model (userAuth) works ok - I just can't seem to pull in the hasOne 
into the form.

I haven't even tried binding the userAuthDetails to a grid yet but suspect that will be equally as challenging

Has anyone managed to get this to work? I only went down the associations route because i thought it would make this sort of stuff cleaner / simpler!

[EDIT]

Giving up trying to do this with a form as I am happy for this data to be read only for now. I am now trying to show this data in an xtemplate within a row expander.

I've tried the following but it does not work!!!

```
plugins: [
    {
        ptype: 'rowexpander',
        rowBodyTpl: [
            '<p><b>Username:</b> {userName}</p>',
            '<p><b>Email:</b> {userAccount.email}</p>',
            '<tpl for="userAuthDetails">',
                 '<p>{provider}</p>',
            '</tpl>'
        ]
    }],
```

What sort of voodoo do I need to make this work? It is not obvious at all!!!

ATM I am thinking I won't be using ExtJs again - I've found myself in too many dark holes like this recently where things blatantly should just work the way you'd expect - just googling this shows everyone expects this to work. I've used ExtJs on and off for years but I think now is the time to finally admit there are better js application frameworks out there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no automatic, config-only way of how to do that. If you look at the `loadRecord` source you see that it just gets data from the passed record and calls `setValues` on the form.

You would need to override `loadRecord` method to dig the required values from the associated record(s).

Comment: That's a real shame - I don't what the point of all this associations is then!!

Comment: Well, form by their nature are not form displaying hierarchical data and associations are used elsewhere. However, I agree that some mappings could be provided so that it would work OOTB.

Comment: What about displaying this data in a template?

Comment: Template is not good for creating components (fields), their purpose is to generate HTML.

Comment: Yesyes but This is a read only view atm so for now this will do :) is it possible to display the association data using templates?

Comment: Yes, you can use XTemplate. You only need to dig data for it from the associated record(s).

Comment: Don't suppose you have an example?

Comment: I have tpl example here: http://extjs.eu/examples/#complex-data-binding and although it doesn't use associated record it can give you an idea. See the source of PersonPanelView.js

Comment: How do you call into the child collection or objects though? I have shown the same technique on my original question with an edit - userAccount.email doesn't work - nothing i have tried works!

Comment: Calling `authDetails()` on hasMany record returns store with belongsTo records. You can iterate through the returned store to collect data from the records and then you the data for the template.